# Toast alert in Android & IOS creat react native expo

Tags: react-native, expo, toast

I am creating an APP using `managed` expo react native.

And want to implement Toast alerts, `react-native` provides `Toast` only for `Android` not for `IOS`.

I googled it and found the couple of modules which works on Android and ios but they required some config change in Native code. But as I said I am working on `Managed` expo app. So, I don't have access for that.

Now let me know how I can implement Toast on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use third-party library **native-base** available for both react-native-cli and expo

[Native-Base] https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html

[Toast Component] https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#toast-def-headref

Comment: Thanks for `native-base` ... As my app is already setup... and using various components from `react-native` module... and `native-base` also provides those components. Here my concern is that, Would it be good to use both `react-native` and `native-base` in an app?

Comment: Yes you can use both according to your need

Comment: No Native base will increase your app size.

Answer (score 7):

**As toast is a native feature in android, for ios try snakbar.**

```
import {
    ToastAndroid,
    Platform
} from "react-native";
import Snackbar from 'react-native-snackbar';

notify = (message) => {
    if (Platform.OS != 'android') {
        Snackbar.show({
            text: message,
            duration: Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT,
        });
    } else {
        ToastAndroid.show(message, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    }
}
```

** If you are on expo
https://snack.expo.io/@mainak/snackbar

Comment: react-native-snackbar doesn't work with Expo: *"Note that because this is a native module, Expo does not support it"*

Comment: thanks @llya, changing my answer and proving support for expo too.